# Right-click for TPopupMenu interpreted as drag-and-drop

Tags: drag-and-drop, popupmenu, c++builder-6

I have a popup menu which works as expected. The drag-and-drop functionality on the same object works as expected. Put them together, and...

The popup menu appears when I right-click. Wile the menu is stil there, a subsequent *left-click* off the popup menu but still on the object invokes the drag-and-drop functionality, as if the initial right-click were a left click which had been held until now and then released.

```
void __fastcall myGrid::eDragDrop(System::TObject *Sender, System::TObject *Source, int X, int Y)
{
  while((Sender != this) && (Sender != NULL))
  {
    TControl *control = dynamic_cast < TControl * > (Sender);
    if(control != NULL)
    {
      X += control->Left;
      Y += control->Top;
      Sender = control->Parent;
    }
    else
    {
      Sender = NULL;
    }
  } // while
  // Check for a drop onto the Chart

  if((Column != NULL)&&(Column->Visible)&& (Column->HeaderIndex>=0))
  {
    int Xt = X - FHeaderSB->Left + FHorzScroll->Position;
    int HeaderIndex = Column->HeaderIndex;
    if((Xt > FHeaderSections->Items[HeaderIndex]->Left) && (Xt < FHeaderSections->Items[HeaderIndex]- >Right))
    {
      Xt -= FHeaderSections->Items[HeaderIndex]->Left;
      GotDragDropTime = true;
      DragDropTime = Column->GetTimeFromPosition(Xt);
    } // if
  } // if Visible


  if(fDragDrop != NULL)
  {
    fDragDrop(Sender, Source, X, Y);
  }
}
```

What have I done wrong? How can I fix this?

Comment: Can you show some code? Do you have any additional code (OnMouseXYZ events) to show the popup or implement drag&drop?

Comment: The code you've shown here is irrelevant since by the time it runs, it's already too late; a drag operation has already started. You need to figure out how you got there in the first place. Tell us about your mouse events and the DragMode property of your control. (Also, the first loop of this function appears to be a reimplementation of `this-> ScreenToClient(Sender->ClientToScreen(x, y))`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it! There was an oversight in a function called in `OnMouseDown` where the `PendingDrag` flag was set without checking which button was clicked.

I hadn't realised how much of the drag functionality was controlled in our code. It was not the fault of Borland C++ Builder 6 after all.

Thank you for the insightful comments. They helped me find the bug.